# What percentage of the global population have more than 8GB of RAM on their computer?

Tags: memory

I have tried to do [a competition of Machine Learning](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/) for but my computer has only 8GB of RAM. I was only able to deal with a ninth of the data. Some where saying that you needed at least twice that amount. Therefore I was wondering what percentage of the global population have more than 8GB of RAM on their computer ? And, therefore, if the machine learning was not reserved for companies or the person able to afford such memory.

Comment: This is a valid question, but I'm not sure it is best addressed on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I do (have 32 GB). But I know about two dozen people's computers, and neither of them does have more than 4GB. It is not a standard yet, and most people don't care to pay extra for the capability even. My guess is less than 1% of all computers do have more than 4GB even.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you for the precision, if it is better and that there is consensus can you ask to migrate it? I have never done it. I still have a little apprehension as far as stack overflow is very programming oriented.

Comment: @Aganju Wow, I did not expect so little. Do you have references?

Comment: Something to keep in mind:  An awful lot of machines are used for very light duty and aren't relevant to your situation.  People who are playing with machine learning will be well above the average user and their machine specs will generally reflect this.

Comment: I have an anecdote, vague & no numbers unfortunately, but directly from the head of a large MMO, who stated "the average user has a less powerful machine than 5 years ago" - due to them all swapping from cheap desktops to cheap laptops. RAM wasn't specifically mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested finding the steampowered hardware survey for reference

https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/Steam-Hardware-Software-Survey-Welcome-to-Steam

I must add this is amongst gamers so there is some bias here.

[image: System Status]

I suggest you contact benchmarking sites and ask them for there results.

http://www.openbenchmarking.org

http://www.userbenchmark.com

Are both open source so they will probably be willing to help you.

3dmark/futuremark is a commericial site and they may or may not being willing to help.

Comment: Great! But is not it limited to the games population? I do not know if it's very representative of the total population?

Comment: @ThePassenger  Its the best I could find on short notice.  I tried 3dmark results,openbenchmarking.org, and userbenchmark.com and so far no average amount of RAM.

Comment: @ThePassenger I don't believe this an accurate representation of a world-wide population.

Comment: @ThePassenger  I suggest you make contact with the sources I added to my answer, they might be willing to help you.

Comment: Gamers would be on the high end.  Most reasonable new desktop systems come with 8 gigs of memory now, up from 4 gigs being typical 5 years ago. I'd imagine that 8 gigs is about average.

Comment: I just sent an email to www.openbenchmarking.org which seems to be part of phoronix but I wasn't able to fund the contact of the second one

Comment: @ThePassenger  userbenchmark   support@userbenchmark.com